# Groundwater Levels for UK

Tags: geospatial

I'm trying to find some open source data for groundwater levels measured from boreholes. The ideal geographic span would be the UK but if it was only England that wouldn't be such a big loss. 
I've found [this](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/realtime-flood-data-groundwater-levels1) government resource for England but the first link directs me to a paid datasource and the second link indicates it is no longer available.
Does anyone have a suggestion as to finding an alternative source of data?

The format of the data would ideally be .shp / WMS or something workable within GIS.